# Apache Server Compatibility with PCI

Tags: apache-2.2, magento, pci-dss

I do not know if this is a proper place to ask, so please help me with this one.

Question: I want to know whether Apache web server is compatible with PCI Compliant Payment environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

<sub>(As with any piece of software, as long as you keep up to date with security patches and updates and as long as you configure it correctly.)</sub>

Please follow the tag [pci-dss](/questions/tagged/pci-dss) and order/search to find a number of really good Q&A's regarding that topic.